# Add required attribute in input field when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a radio button with an id="radio-jadwal". I want to make my 2 input fields (date and time) become required when the button is clicked. What's the best solution for this one. Thanks in advance

Comment: if else is the best solution I thing

Answer (score 3):

You have to do implement two steps.
Call a method on click of the radio button.
Afterwards make sure it was marked as check and the add the required attribute to your inputs.

```js
function clickHandler(radio) {
  
   document.getElementById("name").required = radio.checked;
   document.getElementById("date").required = radio.checked;
   
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-jadwal" onclick="clickHandler(this);">
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="date" id="date">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `if (radio.checked)` you don't even need it, just assign the values directly, as it's bool, it will be either true or false

Comment: Good point. Changed my answer  @AbhishekPandey

Comment: also it should be change, instead of click, so It can work in grouped radios

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way :

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#radio-jadwal');
let inputRequired = document.querySelectorAll('input[class="input-required"]');

input.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    if(this.checked)
    {
        inputRequired.forEach((index, i) =>
        {
            index.setAttribute('required', true);
            console.log(index);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        inputRequired.forEach((index, i) =>
        {
            index.setAttribute('required', false);
            console.log(index);
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" id="radio-jadwal">
      <input type="date" class="input-required">
      <input type="time" class="input-required">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `if (radio.checked)` you don't even need it, just assign the values directly, as it's bool, it will be either true or false, you can reduce many line of codes

Comment: why `'input[class="input-required"]'` why not `'input.input-required'` or `'.input-required'`?

Comment: It's just a way to identify specific elements. There are many ways to do it ;) @AbhishekPandey

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using vanilla JavaScript-

Define a boolean(say x) which will change its value depending upon whether the radio-button is checked(1) or not(0). If x is 1, then use "setAttribute()" to add the "required" functionality to the elements. If x is 0, then use "removeAttribute()" to remove the "required" functionality.

2. If you are using something like React, then use a state variable to track the "checked" or "unchecked" state of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='radio' id='radio-jadwal'>Checked
<input type='text' class='cm'>
<input type='text' class='cm'>

<script>
    $('#radio-jadwal').click(function() {
        $(".cm").prop('required',true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -2):

```
<form>
<fieldset id="group1">
    <input type="radio" value="">
    <input type="radio" value="">
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="group2">
    <input type="radio" value="">
    <input type="radio" value="">
    <input type="radio" value="">
</fieldset>
```